# "The file name is not valid" error when trying to use "Get Group from Matched Text"

Tags: shortcuts-app

I have a shortcut which is invoked via an action sheet when sharing a URL.

When invoked, it eventually gets the HTML of the webpage via:

1. Accepts URLs
2. Get contents of [URL]
3. Make HTML from [Contents of URL]

   The HTML at this stage is something like this:

   ```
   <a href="http://www.example.com">Click here</a>
   ```
4. Match `<a href="([^"]+)">Click here</a>` in [HTML from Rich Text]
5. Get [Group At Index] [1] in [Matches]
6. Show [Text] in Quick Look

Step 5 is inserted for debugging purposes. However, instead of showing me the URL it was able to parse, it shows me a page saying:

> The file name is not valid

---

To debug the issue, I tried removing steps 1-3, and replacing it with text:

1. Text

   ```
   <a href="http://www.example.com">Click here</a>
   ```
2. Match `<a href="([^"]+)">Click here</a>` in [HTML from Rich Text]
3. Get [Group At Index] [1] in [Matches]
4. Show [Text] in Quick Look

Now Quick Look suddenly does work. I.e. it shows me:

> http://www.example.com

What is going on here, and why can I only get it to work with static text and not an action sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Another way I debugged this issue was I changed what it was matching. E.g. instead of matching the URL, I decided to match the "Click here" to see what would happen:

1. Accepts URLs
2. Get contents of [URL]
3. Make HTML from [Contents of URL]

   The HTML at this stage is something like this:

   ```
   <a href="http://www.example.com">Click here</a>
   ```
4. Match `<a href="[^"]+">(Click here)</a>` in [HTML from Rich Text]
5. Get [Group At Index] [1] in [Matches]
6. Show [Text] in Quick Look

Sure enough, this worked. Quick Look showed me:

> Click here

This made it clear that there is something going on with text that happens to be in the format of a URL in Quick Look.

The `Get Type` (along with Quick Look right after it) was helpful in debugging and figuring out what the issue was.

There were a few non-obvious things going on here:

- When testing as a shortcut, the type of the text before reaching Quick look was `Rich text`. When testing with the Text action, the type of the text before reaching Quick look was `Text`.
- If Quick Look receives `Text` (even if it looks like a URL), it'll display the URL as plain text.
- If Quick Look receives text that looks like a URL of type `Rich text`, then it will try to display the contents of the URL, as though it's a local file (or something like that). This will most likely result in the `The file name is not valid` error mentioned above.

The fix, then, is to force the contents to be converted into plain text by adding an extra step right before the Quick Look:

1. Accepts URLs
2. Get contents of [URL]
3. Make HTML from [Contents of URL]

   The HTML at this stage is something like this:

   ```
   <a href="http://www.example.com">Click here</a>
   ```
4. Match `<a href="([^"]+)">Click here</a>` in [HTML from Rich Text]
5. Get [Group At Index] [1] in [Matches]
6. Get text from [Text]
7. Show [Text] in Quick Look